# How can I put borders on the top of a pentagon shape with CSS?

Tags: html

I would like a roof in div style overlapping on my house base. I have tried to find many how to that teach about the overlapping html but it didn't work like i imagined . . or I did it wrong ?

I tried this (the green one):

[image: a house i have tried]

And I expected this (the pink zone):

[image: a house in my imagine]

```css
.outer {
  max-width: 700px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #87935B;
  padding: 10px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 25%, 50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  z-index: -500;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}

.inner {
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #ffdbbb;
  padding: 10px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 25%, 50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  z-index: 500;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I converted your code to use classes. Inline styles are very difficult to work with. In general, don't use them.

Comment: try making it into an svg

Comment: Agree with @wondering Too many people forget that CSS is not a drawing tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **:before** pseudo-element to create an overlapping roof on top of a house base by defining its size, shape, and position in your CSS. I know its not exactly the same, But you can try different combinations in the pseudo-element **:before**

```css
.house {
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px; /* Adjust the width of the house */
  height: 150px; /* Adjust the height of the house */
  background-color: violet; /* House base color */
}

.house:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px; /* Adjust the position of the roof relative to the house */
  left: -20px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 120px solid transparent; /* Adjust the size and shape of the roof */
  border-right: 120px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 40px solid purple; /* Roof color */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>House Shape</title>
</head>
  
<body>
 <div class="house"></div>
</body>

</html>
```